# jMeter Groovy decrypt message with rsa private key from string

Tags: encryption, groovy, jmeter, private-key, jsr223

I'm trying to write a Groovy script in order to use it in a JSR223 Sampler in JMeter.
This script should get a String RSA private key and decrypt a message.

This is my code:

```
// This is what I want to decrypt
def sessionToken = vars.get('SESSION_TOKEN') 

def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance('RSA')
def factory = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

// My string private key
def privateKeyString = "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"

def keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString.getBytes());
def encodedKeySpec = new java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
def privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec)

cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
cipherText = cipher.doFinal(sessionToken.getBytes())
log.info('SESSION TOKEN Decrypted: ' + cipherText)
```

After I'm running my code, I got an error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :(.

Extra info: I don't have Groovy / Java programming experience.

Thank you!

Comment: How long is `sessionToken.getBytes()`? And is a charset encoding really correct or is maybe a Base64 decoding required? Furthermore, encoding (in `getBytes()`) and padding (in `Cipher.getInstance()`) should be specified.

Comment: Hello @Topaco, 
I changed a little the code with your suggestions:

`def sessionBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sessionToken.getBytes());`

`def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")`

`cipherText = cipher.doFinal(sessionBytes)`

The message is decrypted but not correctly :(.

Result is: `YTJlZWQzMTMtMTViOC00ODFmLTk4MDItYjAwNjNhMjIzYTBk`

My expected result should be: `a2eed313-15b8-481f-9802-b0063a223a0d`

Comment: `YTJlZWQzMTMtMTViOC00ODFmLTk4MDItYjAwNjNhMjIzYTBk` is just the Base64 encoding of `a2eed313-15b8-481f-9802-b0063a223a0d`, s. e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/. So do a Base64 decoding.

Comment: I tried in an online editor: [Groovy editor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php) 

This:
`def test = "YmYzYjI4ZGUtZWIxMS00YmE0LTk3NzMtMTY5Y2ZmYzRiMzg1"`

`def decodeTest = test.decodeBase64().toString()`

`println decodeTest`

`def decodeTest2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(test.getBytes());`
`println decodeTest2`

Output is:
`[98, 102, 51, 98, 50, 56, 100, 101, 45, 101, 98, 49, 49, 45, 52, 98, 97, 52, 45, 57, 55, 55, 51, 45, 49, 54, 57, 99, 102, 102, 99, 52, 98, 51, 56, 53]`

Comment: Found the way to do it in Groovy:
`def string = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("YOUR STRING HERE".getBytes()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Topaco (thank you!) I was able to make the script to work.

Firstly I had to decode my message:

```
def sessionBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sessionToken.getBytes());
```

Then I had to add the padding to the chiper:

```
def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
```

And in the end I had to decode my result from cipher:

```
def string = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("YOUR STRING HERE".getBytes()));
```

Final script:

```
def sessionToken = "N9Tuh2bvXAQulujXQpSq5xJne+hNaUrsue0X1eOccPxZNhCwWt9/7yXgNv6eULRjCv1fiuuBQ3AchJU2qQp7/PuszHqYYzr6G8k0sYsB2oYR226+so5Ntsnaq61JUr461/jtoxnE3P9hqKwz4NIXjhlB78oVhWsOLeVx69wRuGY="

def sessionBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sessionToken.getBytes());

def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
def factory = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

def privateKeyString = "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"

def keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString.getBytes());
def encodedKeySpec = new java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
def privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec)

cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
cipherText = cipher.doFinal(sessionBytes)

def encodedSessionToken = cipherText.encodeBase64().toString()

def decodedSessionToken = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedSessionToken.getBytes()));

println decodedSessionToken
```